# Why I am getting Command failed error at ChildProcess.onExit() while converting pdf to image?

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, graphicsmagick

I am converting pdf file to image line in png format using "pdf2pic" npm. But I am always getting the below error. Anyone have solution for this. I will be thankful to you:
I already installed-> imagemagick,graphicsmagick.

```
node:9672) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Command failed: 
        at ChildProcess.onExit (E:\Node API\NodeTestAPI\node_modules\gm\lib\command.js:301:17)        
        at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
        at ChildProcess.cp.emit (E:\Node API\NodeTestAPI\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:29)
        at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1058:16)
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:293:5)
    (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
    (node:9672) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
```